# Get API in components of Notification by Real Time - NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I have a dumb question I think but I need your help.
I am creating a **Notification components which always get noti by Axios Real Time (Reload everytime)** but I'm confusing to make it.

My Notification Components:

```
<template>
   <ul class="tab-content">
     <notification-item></notification-item>
   </ul>
</template>
<script>
import ItemNotification from '~/components/header/NotificationItem.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    'notification-item': ItemNotification
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getNotification')
  }
}
</script>
```

Modules Notification: **/store/notification.js**:

```
import api from '~/plugins/axios'

const state = () => {
  return {
    notifications: null
  }
}

const actions = {
  getNotification ({commit}, config) {
    api.get(`/notifications/`, config)
    .then(response => {
      commit('GET_NOTIFICATION', response.data)
    })
  }
}
const getters = {}

const mutations = {
  GET_NOTIFICATION (state, notifications) {
    state.notifications = notifications
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

This line this.$store.dispatch('getNotification') doesn't work? How can I do it in the best way or do you guys have example project in Github show me. Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using nuxt.js which is server side rendered.

[`mounted()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) lifecycle hook is not called  during server-side rendering.

So dispatch the action in `created()` hook

```
created () { 
   this.$store.dispatch('getNotification') 
}
```

**EDIT:**
You can setup  a watcher on `$route` property which will be called whenever the route changes as follows:

```
watch: { 
    '$route' (to, from) { 
        // react to route changes... 
        this.$store.dispatch('getNotification') 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's right. It works. But please help me the issue that How can I make this Notification Components always reload methods GetNotifications in Real TIme?

Comment: @FeedGit what do you mean by reload methods?

Comment: Like Notification of Facebook, it reloads when change url!!